# How to prevent double clicks on MVC Html.SubmitButton

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How do you prevent double clicks on MVC Html.SubmitButton using jQuery, it also need to take into consideration the validation controls on the form.

Can someone show a code sample

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
$('#yourButtonId').click(function() {
    // Check validation before disabling
    if ($(this.form).valid()) {
         this.disabled = 'disabled';
    }        
});
```

Note that this will work for MVC3 unobtrusive validation, not sure if that's what you're using.

Comment: Simplest and cleanest solution thanks! I used this but instead of Id I used class.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I use.You can get more specific with the selector As this script is used on a very simple page.

```
  $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#butSubmit', this).removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
    });

    $('form').submit(function ()
    {
        if ($(this).valid())
        {
            $('#butSubmit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a javascript function on the button, and disable the button or hide it.

Comment: I think I need to clarify my question a bit further, I know its achieved like that but I need a code sample.  Hiding it would be easy but like I said validation controls should be considered